# What heading to use in a Bootstrap alert

Tags: accessibility, alerts, bootstrap, screen-reader, heading

In Bootstrap there are dedicated alerts.
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/alerts/

According to the code on that site, the headings in an alert shall be h4, but I'm not quite sure that's the correct heading level.

- If I use h1, there will be two h1 headings on the same page.
- If i use h2, there will be a h2 before the h1 on that page.
- If I avoid using headers, users with screen readers (just braille, no speach)
  might miss the information when browsing that page.

Are there any other options except of those above, or are any of these options the correct way to handle this issue?

**UPDATE**: I do refer to cases when these alerts are places at the very top of the page, above all the other content. Example: Cookie info or "Site will be closed tomorrow". These alerts sometimes do have a heading.

Comment: I really don't know, but I assume you shouldn't use any headings since it's just an alert, therefore no headings or content. A different thing would be if you're talking about dialog boxes. So I'd follow @SanjuAus answer advice. Then again, just an opinion. As for your screen reader concerns, the `role=alert` tag should suffice, no need for headings

Answer (score 2):

There can’t be a general answer, it depends on the context and nature of the alert.

#### Context in the markup

HTML 5.1 [recommends](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sections.html#headings-and-sections) to

> use headings of the appropriate rank for the section’s nesting level

If you want to follow this advice (you don’t *have* to, you could for example use `h1` everywhere, if you use sectioning content elements explicitly everywhere), you have to change the heading element depending on the position (in the markup) of the alert:

- It would have to be a `h2` here:

  ```
  <article>
    <h2>Article title</h2>
  </article>
  <section><!-- ALERT --></section>
  ```
- It would have to be a `h3` here:

  ```
  <article>
    <h2>Article title</h2>
    <section><!-- ALERT --></section>
  </article>
  ```
- etc.

#### Where to place it in the markup?

This depends on the nature of the alert. What is it related to?

If the alert is related to a blog post on the page, it might make sense to place it within the blog posting’s `article`. This is especially the case if the alert should always be shown together with the post, for example when it’s read in a feed reader.

If the alert is related to the whole page (i.e., not related to some content on that page), it can make sense to place it as top-level entry in the document outline. To achieve this, you have to use another `h1` as heading within the `body`:

```
<body>
  <h1>Alert heading</h1>
  <h1>Site heading</h1>
</body>
```

(If it makes sense, it’s perfectly fine to have multiple `h1` elements within the `body` sectioning root.)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not quite sure that's the correct heading level.

First of all, if you are indicating about the size of the text, you can retain `h4` and still make font size bigger using `style` attribute. It's just the matter of preference.

Also you don't need to worry about multiple `h1` elements in the same page as long as you provide different id's for each of them. You could even enclose the text in `div` and specify the `style` attribute according to your need and it would just work fine, but you shouldn't because it's a bad practice and would affect the readability of your code.

Comment: I think you mean "as long as they're in different `sections`". Multiple H1 are forbidden by w3 specs unless they're inside their own section (then you can have one h1 header per section) . https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements

Comment: @Devin: Multiple `h1` in the same section are not forbidden (each one after the first creates an implicit section).

Comment: @Devin As unor pointed out, it's not actually forbidden but it would mess with some SEO tools out there especially those which search for the h1 tags as clues to what the page's content is about. It's briefed in this [article](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-truth-about-multiple-h1-tags-in-the-html5-era--webdesign-16824).